# Layout format option to use for a width or height constraint?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm using the visual format language to create width and height constraints in code. Like this:

```
[myView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                        constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[myView(100)]"
                                            options:NSLayoutFormatAlignmentMask
                                            metrics:nil
                                              views:views]];
```

But I really don't know what `NSLayoutFormatOption` I should be using for the options. One is required for the code to work, but `NSLayoutAttributeLeft` and the similar ones have nothing to do with width. What should I use for the option in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 0 if it doesn't make sense to pass any options.

See Apple's examples in their [Auto Layout Guide: Created Constraints Programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH11-SW1).

For Swift, use can use the the format options:

```
NSLayoutFormatOptions.allZeros
```

Comment: 0 causes compiler warning